# Spring boot not-null property references

Tags: spring, spring-boot

i am creating a spring boot project inventory system. while i creating a project i ran into the problem with `not-null property references a null or transient value : com.example.crud.entity.Item.itemname`
what i tried so far i attached below of .ItemController and entity,repo,sevices below of item.i got the ItemServiceIMPL i don't know what was the problem

ItemController

```
public ResponseEntity<StandardResponse> saveItem(@RequestBody ItemSaveDTO itemSaveDTO)
    {
        String id = itemService.addItem(itemSaveDTO);
        return new ResponseEntity<StandardResponse>(
                new StandardResponse(
                        201,id + "item successfully" , id
                ), HttpStatus.CREATED
        );
    }
```

Item

```
public class Item
{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "item_id", length = 50)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int itemid;

    @Column(name = "item_name", length = 100,nullable = false)
    private String itemname;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "mesuring_unit", length = 100,nullable = false)
    private MesuringUnitType measuringUnit;

    @Column(name = "balance_qty", length = 100,nullable = false)
     private double balanceQty;

    @Column(name = "supplier_price", length = 100,nullable = false)
    private double supplierprice;

    @Column(name = "active", columnDefinition = "TINYINT default 1")
    private  boolean active;
}
```

ItemRepo

```
@EnableJpaRepositories
@Repository
public interface ItemRepo extends JpaRepository<Item,Integer> {

}
```

ItemService

```
public interface ItemService  {
    String addItem(ItemSaveDTO itemSaveDTO);
}
```

ItemServiceIMPL

```
    @Autowired
    private ItemRepo itemRepo;
    @Autowired
    private ItemMapper itemMapper;

    @Override
   public String addItem(ItemSaveDTO itemSaveDTO) {

       Item item = itemMapper.RequestDtoToEntity(itemSaveDTO);
        item.setActive(true);
        if(!itemRepo.existsById(item.getItemid()))
        {
           return itemRepo.save(item).getItemname();
        }
        else
       {
            System.out.println("already in database");
           return null;
        }

   }
```

ItemMapper

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface ItemMapper {
    Item RequestDtoToEntity(ItemSaveDTO itemSaveDTO);

}
```

StandardResponse

```
public class StandardResponse {

    private int code;
    private String message;
    private Object data;
}
```

Comment: As mentioned in an earlier question remove the `@Repository` and `@EnableJpaRepositories` as they have no use. Add your `ItemSaveDTO` as the problem is probably in the  mapping (not matching property names **or** the JSON you are actually sending to the controller). Finally please add code with package and import statements!